# Remove extra zeros in Pascal

Tags: string, pascal, leading-zero

I created a calculator in Pascal and I want to dynamically remove any extra decimal zeros. For example:

- if the result is `4.12` it should only show

  > 4.12
- but if the result is `15` it should only show

  > 15

When I use `write(number)` the number automatically appears with all the decimals possible, which in most cases are a bunch of zeros. I'm using [Pascalzim](http://pascalzimbr.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html).

Comment: This probably varies by the exact incarnation of Pascal that you are using, so specify that.

Comment: It absolutelly does depend on the dialect you are using. In Borland-related dialects you specify width and precision using colons: `write( x:7:2 )`, for example.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I am using Pzim

Comment: By "_specify that_" you are meant to edit your original question, instead of misinterpreting comments as a chat. Most likely nobody knows Pascalzim if not speaking Portuguese, so you could have mentioned that and actually linked to it (because this is the internet, which works because of links). Also your question is not clear enough which actual output you have - what are "_all decimals possible_" actually?

Answer (score 0):

> […] if the result is 4.12 […]

The problem is, it is highly likely you are *incapable* of storing the number `4.12`.
Depending on your processor (i. e. compiler, machine/hardware, operating system, etc.), the result is *very likely* a mere *approximation* of `4.12`.
This *is* Pascal’s definition of `real`, a sufficiently precise approximation.
Example:

```pascal
program realDemo(output);
    var
        x: real;
    begin
        x := 412 / 100;
        writeLn(x:1:62);
    end.
```

prints (result varies among different implementations of `real`)

```
4.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875000000000000
```

The junk inbetween are due to the processor’s incapability of storing `4.12`.
The final series of zeros are due to lack of data.
Your task is now to find out whether some “random” digits are *legit* results or due to the computer’s inability of storing the number.

- You could say, for instance, 8 consecutive zeros separate the result from any junk digits.
  However, the result of `8000000004 / 1000000000` is legitimately `8.000000004` and not `8`.
- You do additional math when your calculator performs an operation.
  Every number becomes associated with a number of [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).
  Any *additional* precision seemingly “gained” *after* performing an operation is bogus.
- Not the most ideal method, but you could do some [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

  ```
           0.666666666666666518636930049979 = result × (1 − epsReal)
  result = 0.666666666666666629659232512494
           0.666666666666666740681534975010 = result × (1 + epsReal)
         ↓ ────────────────────────────────
           0.666666666666666                  common digits
  ```

  The [`epsReal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) constant is an extension of ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”.
  Obviously in the common digits part you’ll remove any trailing zeros past the decimal point.

One last option shall not be left unmentioned, but you are not obligated to use the built-in arithmetic operators and data types.
Using [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), however, is probably beyond the typical calculator program you implement for educational exercise.